# Why is Stack Overflow asking me constantly about cookies?

Tags: bug, cookies

I already responded to the cookies banner five times today, but when reloading the page I get:

[image]

*Customize Settings* doesn't work at all.

I'm using Firefox 111.0.1 (64-bit) on [macOS 13.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura. 22E261).

Comment: One prerequisite for *Customize Settings* working [is JavaScript allowed from *cookielaw.org*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#comment1200676_71208). Though even when blocked, it doesn't cause this problem (at least not on its own).

Comment: No repro on Firefox 112.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 (yes, I know). Though on other Stack Exchange sites, it does occasionally ask (timescale days to weeks. No clear pattern; erratic).

Comment: Happens to me with FireFox on Windows 10 once or twice a day.

Comment: I am getting this on every single request (i have already cleared the cookies) ... but this only happened in the last couple days and it was when i was 150 miles away and suspended my laptop and then brought it back up when home (assuming coincidence on that) ... **UPDATE** the first duplicate answer (that has 1 answer) fixed it for me [adding `stackoverlfow.com` to the unprotected sites list for DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials]

Comment: @lagbox you have a typo: stackover - lfow - .com